# Send telegram from Raspberry Pi when button is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gsm, telegram

I am doing a project which uses Telegram on the Raspberry Pi. Currently, I am using a XBEE to read high inputs when the button is pressed. Currently, I am able to send SMS when the button is being pressed. I intend to implement telegram in my codes so that it will send both a SMS and also a Telegram message.I have also installed Telegram API on my RPI. How do include code to start the telegram server and send a message.

My codes are below,

```
if stat1.strip() in "Enable enable ENABLE":

            try:
                    recipient= ( )
                    for item in numbers:
                            recipient= item[0]
                            print recipient
                            gsm.send_sms(recipient, 'Panic activated!')
                            sendSmsNow = True
                            print "panic message sent"
                            time.sleep(5)

            except Exception as e:
                    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py) for sending messages from Python to Telegram. There are some examples in the examples folder of the project.

The gist of it:

```
from telegram import Updater
import logging

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments bot and
# update. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(bot, update):
    bot.sendMessage(update.message.chat_id, text='Hi!')
```

Check out the code [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot2.py).